# Classe C# como parâmetro no SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, servidor

Tem como criar uma classe no C# e a mesma classe no SQL Server que representa-se uma `tabela (ID, Nome, Telefone)` e criar uma procedure onde eu passaria como parâmetro está classe .

Este é o exemplo da classe

```
puclic class Cliente
{
     public int ID;
     public string Nome, Telefone;
}
```

Na hora de ler os dados do banco eu chamaria a procedure exemplo `PROC_Select_Cliente` e esta procedure me retorna-se um objeto da classe cliente.

Na hora do insert eu chamaria a procedure `PROC_Insert_Cliente` passando como parâmetro uma instância da classe cliente onde há todas as informações.

Não sei se isso existe por isso não tenho um código para mostrar.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo! Sua pergunta está um pouco confusa. Tem algum código que você já está trabalhando? Você quer apenas persistir um objeto em um banco de dados e poder recuperá-lo para manipular?

Comment: Recomendo recorrer o uso de Entity Framework. Pesquisa e não é difícil a utilização

Answer (score 3):

A maneira fácil e simples é usando [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper).

## Executando Stored Procedure para Seleção

```
var cliente = connection.Query<Cliente>("PROC_Select_Cliente", new {ID = 1}, 
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
```

## Executando Stored Procedure para Inserção

```
var parametros = new DynamicParameters();
parametros.Add("@ID", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
parametros.Add("@Nome", "Fulano");
parametros.Add("@Telefone", "(11) 2345-6789");

connection.Execute("PROC_Insert_Cliente", parametros, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure); 

int id = parametros.Get<int>("@ID");
```

Lembrando que `connection` é qualquer objeto que implemente [`IDbConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.idbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx). Pode ser [`SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx), por exemplo.

Agora, passar um objeto para uma função que executa uma *Stored Procedure* é um passo um pouco mais além. Não sei se vale a pena detalhar nesta resposta.

Comment: Se você pudesse me passar um link ou uma ideia de como fazer.

Comment: Posso fazer um vídeo. O que acha?